# Get a number froma range with the number format

Tags: excel, vba

I need to retrieve a number from a cell with the format e.g. cell A1 contains the number "001", but when I apply that to a variable it becomes "1". How do i retrieve "001"??

```
Tgtval = Range("A1")
```

Comment: How is `Tgtval` declared? It works for me when I declare as String.

Comment: Declared as a string, using the Text property works. It may be because I am actually retrieving multiple values in this way with extra character inbetween so
`Tgtval = Range(“A1”) & “-“ & Range(“A2”) & “-“ & Range(“A3”)`

Comment: When you pull information with only `Range("A1")` it defaults to using the `.value` property. I've always been a fan of declaring all properties explicitly to avoid unwanted issues like this. (in this case using `.text`)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `Text` property:

```
Tgtval = Range("A1").Text
```